# Microsoft Word 365 problems

Tags: capslock, autocorrect, typing, microsoft-word-365

Word 365

Can you turn off the capslock so that you dont have the problem of typing a word in Word 365 that has a capital letter in the middle of it rather than an 'a'?  this seems to happen to me a lot, enough to slow me down considerably when I am typing on my laptop and I spend lots of time going back in to correct it.

Also, connected to this problem is there a way to make the space bar only insert one space when typing up a document lastly can you stop your keyboard from adding several iterations of a letter when typing, I have fine motor skills problems and a slight shake, so sometimes when I type I end up with several letters in a word where I only wanted one of them.

Thank you in advance.

regards
pim

Comment: You may want to turn on FilterKeys on your computer. See https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht500119-how-to-turn-on-and-turn-off-filter-keys-windows-ideapad

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems are with the OS settings, not with MS Word.  In Windows you can extend the time that a key repeats a character.

Control Panel -> Keyboard (opens keyboard properties) -> "Repeat delay" and "Repeat rate"

Mac is basically the same.  Go to preferences->keyboard and there is the same option.

For turning off caps lock, my recommendation is just try to get used to not hitting it.  However, you can turn it off.  This link tells how:

https://wikihow.com/Turn-Off-Caps-Lock